# Python Drop first occurrence of list Item from two lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a dice roller with die cancellation using python. I have created the die rolls and stored them in a list. `0` is the first set of dice rolls, `1` is the second set of dice rolls.

```
{0: [4,2,3,2], 1: [2,3,6]}
```

the python script finds the first matching number on both lists for each unique number then drops them off the list.

after result:

```
{0: [4,2], 1: [6]}
```

I cant seem to find the right method to acheive this. I've looked into `itertools` and `find_first` but I cant think of a way to make it work.

Does anyone have any tips?

Comment: That seems to be a dictionary, not a list

Comment: @user3483203 he means `[4,2,3,2]` and `[2,3,6]`

Comment: "First", as defined how?  By the order in which it appears in the first list?  In the second?

Comment: @Roberto better to ask for clarification than assume things.

Comment: It'd be cool if you could provide a step-by-step on how to go from [4,2,3,2] and [2,3,6] to [4,2] and [6]. I didn't get the rules either.

Comment: What happened to number 3 in result?  Please clarify what are you trying to achieve and perhaps give some more examples.

Comment: @user3483203: thanks, yes dictionary sorry. im fairly new to python so my terminology might be a little off. ;)

https://github.com/mschippr/EoTWDice/blob/master/roll.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a try :

```
dct = {0: [4, 2, 3, 2], 1: [2, 3, 6]}
new_dct = dct[0].copy()
for i in new_dct:
    if i in dct[1]:
        dct[0].remove(i)
        dct[1].remove(i)
print(dct)
```

**Update :**

if you need you can change

```
new_dct = dct[0].copy()
for i in new_dct:
```

to

```
for i in dct[0][:]:
```

Comment: Yes, that give the correct output that i'm after. Thanks for your help.

Comment: its glad to help you @MarkSchipper :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this would help you:

```
l0_ = [4,2,3,2]
l0 = list(l0_) # this is needed to make a deep copy of l0_
l1 = [2,3,6]
for i in l0_:
    if i in l1:
        l0.remove(i)
        l1.remove(i)
res = {0:l0, 1:l1}
res
```

If you want to not consider the repetition, you can cast the lists into sets first.